# Is there a way to access the value of `args[0]` in a class from a sub package

Tags: java, program-entry-point

My project consists of a package `one` and a sub package `onePointOne`. The class of my main method is in `one`. There's a method in which I want to use the value of `args[0]`. The method is in a class in `onePointOne`. Is there a way to use the value of `args[0]` in my class without generating an object from my main class?

Edit (Code):

```
package one;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}

package one.onePointOne;

public class TheOtherClass {

    public void someMethod() {
         String iWantTheValueOfArgsHere = // that's what I'm looking for
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
Thanks for the down votes, because obviously everyone who is new to something and has a question at it, could have just googled the problem, because it's simple. Stupid me.

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, why not post some actual example code that illustrates what you're asking?

Comment: Just pass `args` from your `main` method to the method in `onePointOne`. (If those are your real class names, you should start following Java naming conventions, btw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
package one;

public class MainClass {

    private static String[] argsCopy;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        argsCopy = args;
    }

    public static String[] getArgs() {
        return argsCopy;
    }
}

package one.onePointOne;

public class TheOtherClass {

    public void someMethod() {
         String iWantTheValueOfArgsHere = one.MainClass.getArgs()[argNumber];
    }
}
```

You can make it more complicated if you're paranoid about someone modifying the argsCopy array -- either copy the array on each call or only provide methods to fetch arg count and individual arg Strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the arguments of the method to accept a String. Then you will pass the string from the main method.

Your code could look like this:

```
package one;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TheOtherClass().someMethod(args[0]);
    }
}

package one.onePointOne;

public class TheOtherClass {

    public void someMethod(String arg) {
        String iWantTheValueOfArgsHere = arg;// that's what I'm looking for
    }
}
```

If you don't want to create an instance of `TheOtherClass` to call `someMethod` just make the method `static`, and use `TheOtherClass.someMethod(args[0]);`.

```
public static void someMethod(String arg) {
    String iWantTheValueOfArgsHere = arg;// that's what I'm looking for
}
```

Anyway, remember to check `args length` before use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `someMethod` is an instance method - you always need an object instance before calling that method.

If you really don't want to create an object instance of `TheOtherClass` than you can make your method "static".

code1:

```
package one;

import one.onePointOne.TheOtherClass;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TheOtherClass.someMethod(args[0]);
    }
}
```

code2:

```
package one.onePointOne;

public class TheOtherClass {

    public static void someMethod(String theValue) {
         String iWantTheValueOfArgsHere = theValue;// that's what I'm looking for
    }
}
```

Java's strength is object orientation. You should ask yourself, why you don't want to create an instance of your second class.